# what is causing my SQL transaction to abort without php noticing?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, kohana, kohana-3

I am doing an SQL transaction from kohana 3.2 framework in PHP with Postgresql 9.0

I get an exception

> Database_Exception [ 0 ]: ERROR: current transaction is aborted,
>   commands ignored until end of transaction block [ SELECT c.* FROM
>   contents c WHERE c.content_id = 129 AND EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM
>   contents tmp WHERE tmp.content_id = c.content_id AND c.content_id =
>   129 GROUP BY tmp.content_id HAVING MAX(tmp.version) = c.version ) ]

which i strange because this implies to me that some SQL prior to this one failed and thus no more SQL statements are being accepted.  However I have all my SQL calls in a try/catch block and do a rollback on catch before rethrowing.

so i should never see this exception right?, Instead expect to see the one before, which would have spoiled the transaction to begin with...

I added logging to my PHP DB driver, and logged the following SQL statements leading up to the problem.  The last SELECT statement below is the one referenced in my exception above.

The statement prior to the exception statement is an INSERT which would be a good candidate for the spoiler, however when i run all these statements by hand they all go thru properly.

```
UPDATE "articles" 
SET article_id = 126, title = 'abc', blurb = 'abc article blurb' 
WHERE "article_id" = 126 

SELECT c.* FROM contents c 
WHERE c.content_id = 127 
AND EXISTS( 
     SELECT NULL FROM contents tmp 
     WHERE tmp.content_id = c.content_id AND c.content_id = 127 
     GROUP BY tmp.content_id HAVING MAX(tmp.version) = c.version 
)

SELECT c.* FROM contents c 
WHERE c.content_id = 128 AND EXISTS( 
    SELECT NULL FROM contents tmp 
    WHERE tmp.content_id = c.content_id AND c.content_id = 128 
    GROUP BY tmp.content_id HAVING MAX(tmp.version) = c.version 
)

INSERT INTO "contents" 
("blurb", "content", "content_id", "content_type_id", "title", "author_id", "version", "editor_id") 
VALUES 
('postit art', 'FEATURE_IMG_david-chan-drawing_IMG_0221.JPG', 128, 2, 'david chan drawing', 5, 2, 4) 

 SELECT c.* FROM contents c 
 WHERE c.content_id = 129 AND EXISTS( 
     SELECT NULL FROM contents tmp 
     WHERE tmp.content_id = c.content_id AND c.content_id = 129 
     GROUP BY tmp.content_id HAVING MAX(tmp.version) = c.version 
 )
```

what is causing my transaction to abort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL server itself will log errors in transactions, along with the SQL that caused them, that might help provide another end of the thread to get hold of?

You might need to define a `log_line_prefix` to help you pick out your client if the database does a lot of different tasks (e.g. sth like `log_line_prefix = '%t %c %q%u@%h:%d '`)

Comment: thanks!  after hunting down the admin, i found that kohana's db was calling last_val() which fails since i have a multi key table.